# How to Xor a string with a password?

Tags: vb.net

This is what I have so far.

```
Public Function XOREncDec(ByVal textToEncrypt As String) As String
    Dim inSb As New StringBuilder(textToEncrypt)
    Dim outSb As New StringBuilder(textToEncrypt.Length)
    Dim c As Char
    For i As Integer = 0 To textToEncrypt.Length - 1
        c = inSb(i)
        c = Chr(Asc(AscW(c)) Xor "password")
        outSb.Append(c)
    Next
    Return outSb.ToString()
End Function
```

However I am getting an error here

```
c = Chr(Asc(AscW(c)) Xor "password")
```

"Conversion from string "password" to type 'Long' is not valid."

Comment: Note that this adds no security whatsoever.

Comment: You can only XOR numeric types. A string is not a numeric type.

Comment: no don't do that. go read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e970bs09%28v=vs.110%29.aspx (Encrypting and Decrypting Data)

Answer (score 1):

First, read the comments about better methods to protect strings.

Then, we can look at your code. You would xor characters with one character at a time from the password, not the whole password. You can use the loop variable with the `mod` operator to get the corresponding index in the password so it will repeat the characters in password along the length of the string.

Using `Asc(Ascw(c))` means that you get the character code for the first character of the string representation of the character code for the character. For example the character `A` would give you the character code `65`, that would implicitly be converted to the string `"65"` to get the character code for the character `6`, which is 54. As you only use the first digit of the character code, it would not be possible to get the original string back.

You should use ony `AscW` to get the character code, and then `ChrW` to turn the adjusted character code back to a character. The `Asc` and `Chr` function doesn't support Unicode characters.

You don't need a `StringBuilder` for the input, you can access the characters directly from the string.

```
Public Function XOREncDec(ByVal textToScramble As String) As String
  Dim builder As New StringBuilder(textToScramble.Length)
  Dim password As String = "password"
  Dim c As Char
  For i As Integer = 0 To textToScramble.Length - 1
    Dim pos As Integer = i mod password.Length
    c = textToScramble(i)
    c = ChrW(AscW(c) Xor AscW(password(pos)))
    builder.Append(c)
  Next
  Return builder.ToString()
End Function
```

Note that I renamed the parameter from `textToEncrypt` to `textToScramble`, as this simple encoding can't be called encryption in any modern sense of the word.

A word of caution also, the string that is the result of encoding will often contain character codes that doesn't correspond to real characters. It works as long as you decode the same string object, but if you for example write the string to a file and then try to read it back, it will most likely get corrupted. To get data that would survive any kind of storage or communication, you would encode the string into bytes, scramble the bytes, and then create a string value from the bytes using for example base64 encoding.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you want to act on the bytes of the string rather than trying to work in Unicode/UTF-whatever, and the resulting bytes should be kept as bytes (maybe Base64-encoded for transmission)... oh, you just wrote that as I was writing this.